# Splitting owned array into owned halves

Tags: arrays, rust

I would like to divide a single owned array into two owned halves—two separate arrays, not slices of the original array. The respective sizes are compile time constants. Is there a way to do that *without copying/cloning the elements*?

```rust
let array: [u8; 4] = [0, 1, 2, 3];

let chunk_0: [u8; 2] = ???;
let chunk_1: [u8; 2] = ???;

assert_eq!(
  [0, 1],
  chunk_0
);
assert_eq!(
  [2, 3],
  chunk_1
);
```

Since it would amount to merely moving ownership of the elements, I have a hunch there should be a zero-cost abstraction for this. I wonder if I could do something like this with some clever use of [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.transmute.html) and [`forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.forget.html). But there are a lot of scary warnings in the docs for those functions.

My main motivation is to operate on large arrays in memory without as many mem copies. For example:

```rust
let raw = [0u8; 1024 * 1024];

let a = u128::from_be_array(???); // Take the first 16 bytes
let b = u64::from_le_array(???); // Take the next 8 bytes
let c = ...
```

The only way I know to accomplish patterns like the above is with lots of mem copying which is redundant.

Comment: https://docs.rs/array-tools/0.2.10/array_tools/fn.split.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is there a reason that you can't just use [`.split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at)? [Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fb274987420fb266686c7dcd514f292)

Comment: @Herohtar See edit with motivation

Comment: Are you wanting `a` to be a `u128` that is stored at the same location as `raw[0..15]`?

Comment: @Herohtar split_at(_mut) [does not](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12828bf85d980e09e2ad1dba0389ef6a) do the trick. That results in (mutable) references to slices, not owned arrays. Yes, I'd like `raw[0..15]` to be treated as a `u128` (except it'd be nice to have a pattern that extends to all types, not just bytes and other primitives... so it can't double-drop the array elements. I expect the solution will probably use `core::mem::forget` at some point)

Comment: @DanielA.White That crate/function [copies memory](https://docs.rs/array-tools/0.2.10/src/array_tools/lib.rs.html#288-303).

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer that you want arrays, not slices. I'm curious, though; what's the problem with slices?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks. In my opinion the problem with slices is e.g. `u128::from_be_bytes(...)` requires an owned array, not a reference to a slice. Because of this, to me it seems the simplest (codewise) way to bridge the gap between data you receive on the wire and primitive data types is through redundant _copying_... take your buffer, copy a slice out into a `[u8; 16]`, then toss that array to `u128::from_be_bytes(...)`. I guess I don't trust/understand compilers well enough to feel comfortable with optimizations and would prefer a solution that is guaranteed not to have redundant copies

Comment: Are you experiencing an issue because of this? Otherwise, it seems like a lot of effort on premature optimization that likely isn't necessary.

Comment: @Herohtar No issues, other than with learning  You're probably right

Comment: If your end goal is to read values from a byte array, consider using something like [`ReadBytesExt`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/latest/byteorder/trait.ReadBytesExt.html) from the `byteorder` crate. It will basically do exactly what you say want to avoid, but that really is what you want and it optimizes nicely. I should point out that if you have an array of bytes and you want a `u128`, then those 16 bytes are going to be copied *at some point*

Comment: It cannot be done without moves, which are essentially copies. But the compiler can optimize them out.

Comment: @kmdreko "those 16 bytes are going to be copied _at some point_" Yes, but when you want to deal with more than one at a time then the signature of e.g. `u128::from_be_bytes(...)` implies either a redundant copy or more calls to e.g. `std::io::Read::read(...)` than necessary. [For example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c86835cc033376fdd9050cf9d01da4cc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::mem:transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) (warning: **unsafe**!):

```rust
fn main() {
    let array: [u8; 4] = [0, 1, 2, 3];

    let [chunk_0, chunk_1]: [[u8; 2]; 2] =
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<[u8; 4], [[u8; 2]; 2]>(array) };

    assert_eq!([0, 1], chunk_0);
    assert_eq!([2, 3], chunk_1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=707a153ecaefced6f3b5e733a6d6c4cd)

Answer (score 6):

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

let raw = [0u8; 1024 * 1024];
    
let a = u128::from_be_bytes(raw[..16].try_into().unwrap()); // Take the first 16 bytes
let b = u64::from_le_bytes(raw[16..24].try_into().unwrap()); // Take the next 8 bytes
```

In practice, I've found the compiler is pretty smart about optimizing this. With optimizations, it will do the above in a single copy (directly into the register that holds `a` or `b`, respectively). As an example, according to [godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/vcffT4G4W), this:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

pub fn cvt(bytes: [u8; 24]) -> (u128, u64) {
    let a = u128::from_be_bytes(bytes[..16].try_into().unwrap()); // Take the first 16 bytes
    let b = u64::from_le_bytes(bytes[16..24].try_into().unwrap()); // Take the next 8 bytes
    (a, b)
}
```

with `-C opt-level=3` compiles into:

```
example::cvt:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        bswap   rax
        mov     rdx, qword ptr [rdi]
        bswap   rdx
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 16]
        ret
```

It's optimized out any extra copies, calling the `try_into` method, possibly panicking, et cetera.

Answer (score 2):

The [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/) library provides a safe wrapper for re-interpretation of any data type that is “plain old data” (more precisely: all possible byte sequences of the right size are valid values), as long as the input and output are the same size (or the input is a slice whose byte-length is divisible by the output type's size). This is equivalent to a `transmute` solution but without needing to write any any new `unsafe` code.

```rust
let array: [u8; 4] = [0, 1, 2, 3];

let [chunk_0, chunk_1]: [[u8; 2]; 2] = bytemuck::cast(array);
```

If you'd like to avoid using additional libraries, I recommend the `try_into()` approach that's already been posted.